# Tool for insertion of translation tags in Django template?

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-templates

Like many Django devs, today I find myself scouring through templates putting in `trans` and `blocktrans` as I internationalise a site.

Is there a tool that will help me identify blocks of text that are candidates for translation tags and speed this process up?

Comment: This question came first and has an answer. Why not vote to close the newer question?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. However it does seem the other one has more/better answers so would be better to keep now.

Comment: It's OK, perhaps it is better to keep the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using "[Django Template i18n lint](https://github.com/rory/django-template-i18n-lint)", which I found mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505463/444991).

It does a pretty good job of finding strings which are not wrapped in `{% trans %}` or 
`{% blocktrans %}` tags.

Try it out. It should definitely speed up things for you.

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate of the mentioned question.