# Find untranslated strings in HTML templates

Tags: python, django, localization

Is there way to find untranslated strings in the HTML templates of my Django application i.e. blocks of text that are not wrapped in `trans` and `blocktrans` tags.

Since we have many templates, it would be a very time-consuming process to go through them manually and check but if there isn't an option, I guess it has to be done the long and tedious way.

Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to write a basic parser which would do it. Refine it as new cases appear while you use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for insertion of translation tags in Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857293/tool-for-insertion-of-translation-tags-in-django-template)

Answer (score 3):

Found this recently, but have not tried it yet.

Doc: http://www.technomancy.org/python/django-template-i18n-lint/

Code: https://github.com/rory/django-template-i18n-lint

Looks like it hasn't been updated in a year but it might provide a good starting spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin template parser to parse your templates, and recurse into all tags that are not instances of `BlockTransTag`